# Unable to Cross check word in string

Tags: python, eclipse

I have simple code that reads from a text file. If I remove the if statement, it outputs each word as expected. However, after putting in the if statement(which is done to find as specific word), it outputs what is shown in the picture below:

[image]

```
with open("tasksUpdateFailedDailyReport_output.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
         for word in line.split():
             if "Filename" in word: 
                 print(word)

print("Done");
```

I'm using Eclipse as an IDE if that changes anything. The goal is to be able to find specific words within this text file to manipulate them.

Comment: conclusion: you have no words containing the `Filename` substring.

Comment: I'm so mad..I meant to type Filepath, which does exist. And Filename, does not :) Thank you!

Comment: note that to match exact words, just do `if "Filepath" in line.split()`